# Apply class to parent if any child elements has a certain class

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with several sections and I want to apply a class to the section if any fields in it have a certain class.

My idea was to watch for any fields with the `has-error` class within the section and display an icon or something in the section header.

Each field sets its class with `ng-class="{'has-error': !value, 'has-success': value}"` and it seems like the order in which the class is updated and the `$watch` event fires is causing issues.

I have setup a plunkr here: https://plnkr.co/edit/1isq3DXXUvSPW5ChYkuM?p=preview

Try erasing and entering a value in the input and you'll see that the parent class isn't "in sync".

Html:

```
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link data-require="font-awesome@4.5.0" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="bootstrap-js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <sws-form-section>
      <sws-form-field label="Test"></sws-form-field>
    </sws-form-section>
  </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.directive('swsFormSection', function() {
    return {
      link: function($scope, element) {
        $scope.$watch(function() {
          var errors = element.find('.has-error').length;
          console.log('outer:' + errors);
          return errors;
        }, function(value) {
          $scope.hasAnyErrors = value;
        });
      },
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div><label ng-class="{\'text-danger\': hasAnyErrors, \'text-success\': !hasAnyErrors}">Errors In Section: {{hasAnyErrors}}</label><div ng-transclude></div>'
    };
  });

module.directive('swsFormField', function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, element) {
      $scope.value = 'testar';

        $scope.$watch(function() {
          var errors = element.find('.has-error').length;
          console.log('inner:' + errors);
          return errors;
        }, function(value) {
          console.log('the value:' + $scope.value);
        });
    },
    template: '<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ \'has-error\': !value, \'has-success\': value }"><label class="control-label">Test</label><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="value"></div><pre>{{value|json}}</pre>'
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `ng-validate`?  You could then just check `$valid` on the form instead of having to observe a bunch of classnames...

Comment: Ah, I should definitively look into that, thanks. But I have several sections per form so I'm not sure how I would go about it.

Comment: And I'm still curious how I'd solve this e.g in case I would want to use something similar for something other than a form

Comment: TBH my answer would be "don't do that."  In general you're much better off in Angular observing the data model, not by observing the DOM. Rather than having the parent element traverse the DOM searching for classnames, it should be traversing the data model for whatever set those classnames in the first place -- or when it's more convenient, have the sub elements set state variables that can be watched for more easily.  (In other words, if `ng-validate` didn't exist, the right way to solve this would be to invent something very much like `ng-validate`...)

Comment: I agree with your thoughts, I shouldn't observe the DOM. Maybe I could have a separate form for each of the sections...

Comment: I made a new plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/1isq3DXXUvSPW5ChYkuM?p=preview . I think this will work! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Daniel Becks suggestion:

> my answer would be "don't do that." In general you're much better off
>   in Angular observing the data model, not by observing the DOM.

I opted to go for using the already existing ng-valid classes and have each section be a separate form, publish the form to the scope and use the form.$valid property in the section header.

```
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.directive('swsFormSection', function() {
    return {
      transclude: true,
      template: '<form name="formSection"><i class="fa" ng-class="{ \'fa-check\': formSection.$valid, \'fa-pencil\': formSection.$invalid }"></i> My Section:<div ng-transclude></form>'
    };
  });

module.directive('swsFormField', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">Test</label><input type="text" required class="form-control" ng-model="value"></div><pre>{{value|json}}</pre>'
  }
});
```

Updated plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/1isq3DXXUvSPW5ChYkuM?p=preview